# Simple regex negation

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm having trouble with a regex, so I figured I'd ask here. Basically, I need it to match URI's for a collection, except for a certain one (`/new`).

i.e.:

```
/properties     # match
/properties/25  # match
/properties/new # rejected
```

I've tried variations on the following, to no avail:

```
/properties(^(/new)).*
```

I think my trouble is with the negation, but I can't quite grok what I'm meant to be doing.. An explanation with the solution would be much appreciated!

Comment: `^` only means negation inside `[]`. Normally it means "beginning of line".

Comment: @sepp2k: … and only if used immediately after the opening `[`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` negates inside a character class (a group of characters in any order surrounded by `[ ]`. You need to use `?!`. You also shouldn't use `.*`. It doesn't add anything. If you want to match anything you just don't put anything :).  Also you don't need to capture the match. Depending on how you're setting it up you may also need to escape the slashes ( `/` )

Try this:

`\/properties(?!\/new)`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use an additional `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond $2 !=new
RewriteRule ^/properties(/(.*))?$ …
```

This will match `/properties`, `/properties/`, and `/properties/…` followed by anything else but not `/properties/new`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
/properties(?!/new)(?:/.*){0,1}
```

the: `(?!/new) is a negative forward lookup, and essentially says: make sure this cannot be matched

the following: (?:/.+){0,1} allows for the matching of additional paths (ie. /25) and is a non-capturing group that says match / followed by zero or more characters, and match it zero to one times as a group.  The {0,1} allows it to match even if there is no /25.

Comment: You don't need `(?:/.*){0,1}. If you're not trying to capture, leaving it blank is all you have to do. Each part of a regex is a rule. If all the rules indicate a match and there are no more rules, then the engine will show that the line matches. Also .* is never a good idea.

Comment: Good point, the forward look ahead on the `/new` is all he needs to prevent that match.  Thanks for the tip.